# use property declared in a process into another wpf appication using cross thread

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application with MVVM structure.

What I am doing is : I have created one WPF application "NotificationApp" for notification purpose and I am running this app from my main application "MyMainApplication". What I want is to get the count of notifications from the "NotificationApp" which is coming in property "NotificationCount" in "MyMainApplication".

In my "D:\Projects\NotificationApp":

```
    private int notificationCount;
    public int NotificationCount
    {
        get
        {
            return notificationCount;
        }
        set
        {
            notificationCount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NotificationCount");
        }
    }
```

NotificationCount = TotalNumberOfNotifications;

In my "D:\Projects\MainApplication" using below code to execute "D:\Projects\NotificationApp":

```
        Process prc = new Process();
        prc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Projects\NotificationApp\bin\Debug\NotificationApp.exe",ContactId.ToString());
        prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        prc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        prc.Start();
```

The notification application is working fine with this code. But how can I access the NotificationCount property (declared in NotificationApp) inside "MyMainApplication" ? Please Help!!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/?q=c%23+Inter+Process+Communication

Answer (score 0):

Intercommunication is little typical and requires creation of named piped. See [this link](http://tech.pro/tutorial/633/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp) for reference.

Except this, a simple way could be adding a medium of communication between both of the applications like a `SQL table` or `txt file` which both your processes can access.